# Is the size of long double 16 bytes or 10 bytes?

Tags: c

I just started learning C and had a question about data types? I learned in theory that a long double has the size of 10 bytes but when I run it with
`long double a; 
printf("Size of long double = %ld bytes\n", sizeof(a));`

The output is 16 bytes. Why is this the case?

Comment: Not a bad question, but it is a duplicate nevertheless :D

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_double which theory did you learn?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_double - says that there are 10 significant bytes but that most compilers implement it as 16 bytes